How to pivot data from vertical to horizontal
Let's say I have an ordernumber table and an associated ordercomments table
select ot.ordernumber, oc.comments
from ordertable ot
left join ordercomments oc on ot.ordernumber = oc.ordernumber

and usually there is only one associated comment (if any) with an ordernumber.
But when there are multiple comments for an order (up to 5) is it possible in T-SQL to easily convert the output from vertical to horizontal, e.g. converting columns A and B below into D-I?
I have tried Pivot, self-join, cross-apply and am getting nowhere.

